# How to define environment variables for containers in multi-stage builds

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Here below is a snippet of my `docker-compose.yaml`...

```
services:
  my_service:
    container_name: 'my_service'
    env_file: 'variables.env'
    build:
      context: '.'
      dockerfile: 'Dockerfile'
    ...
```

... and here is the referenced `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM golang:alpine as builder
RUN go build -o /build/my_service .
...

FROM alpine
...
COPY –from=builder /build/my_service .
CMD["./my_service"]
```

The problem is that when the final container (the one defined in the last stage) is started, the environment variables defined in the file specified by the `env_file` directive are not set.

Reading the documentation I've understood environment variables defined with `env_file` are meant for the container, not for the build process. Am I missing something?

Comment: no. as I know for both side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated docker-compose from version 1.17.1 to version 1.22.0 and now it works. Finally, just consider that `container_name` is a trap option and should be avoided as much as possible. See [this thread](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6116) for more details.